# CORS Error when POST image

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, slim

I'm using Ionic 3 and an own REST Api using Slim Framework with full access to the server.

Every API call (GET, POST, PUT and DELETE) despite of this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file",image);
return this.httpClient.post("https://myurl.com/api/v1/image,formData)
```

The imageURL is my server API and image is the path which I get from the cordova camera plugin.

This is my Server error:

```
[Error] Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://hobbyrea.com/api/v1/user/image due to access control checks.
```

This is what my server-side headers looks like:

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});
```

Can anybody give me an advice why I get the error with this API call?

EDIT:

I access the API from an iPhone.

EDIT 2:
I use the cordova file-transfer plugin. Please keep in mind to upgrade the upload_max_filesize in the PHP settings. It would save you a lot of headache :D

Comment: i think related with your ionic. have you configure the proxy? like this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38359981/2249037

Comment: Where does this request come from: http://localhost:8080

Comment: try Mozilla Firefox it may wont rise this issue

Comment: Check in network (devTools) if OPTION request has passed and it's accepted. It's standard procedure with sending preflight request. Maybe your backend need to check if this is a option request and accept it.

Comment: @Henry I edited my answer. The requests comes from an iPhone

Comment: @Sh4m I already used proxies. But this doesn't work either

Comment: @Szarik Like I already wrote. Every request works just the upload api doesn't

Comment: @TdoubleG its very long time ago im facing this.. but im using angularjs run on npm server.. and call slim php on apache server.. i manage solve that on npm server.. i just need to add those CORS config...

Comment: @TdoubleG sorry my bad, just another thought shouldn't you add headers also to request? look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44417931/4700863)

Comment: @Szarik unfortunately  this doesn't work. thank you anyway for your help :)

Comment: @Sh4m this doesn't work also. I'm a little bit confused because I run "ionic cordova run ios --device". I don't get it why it's origin is "localhost:8080" and not something like "file://"

Comment: @TdoubleG last shot, I used to have this problem when there was internal error at backend. Check logs, maybe you are sending something that server can't handle or something like this.

Comment: @Szarik the request works. It works on Postman :/. It's just the CORS Error...

Comment: @TdoubleG maybe it's cordova issue try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398805/4700863)

Comment: @Szarik nope, that doesn't work.

Comment: Here is the [solution](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) for CORS when you run in browser. If you run in device, normaly you will **not** face CORS issue. But if you use [WKWebView](http://blog.ionic.io/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/) in ios, you need to use [@ionic-native/http](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) for your request

Comment: @Duannx this doesn't work either. I wonder why the image upload works with the cordova file transfer plugin for some images. With other images I get an error from my server "filename could not be empty"

Comment: @TdoubleG: Oh. it is not a CORS issue

Comment: I found the problem why the cordova plugin fails. It was because of the upload_max_filesize setting for PHP. So I'm using the plugin now for uploading. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Add the client's Origin to your server's allowed origins header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
```